# Scroll down one line without moving the cursor (Vim's `Ctrl-E`) in Emacs

Tags: vim, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

The shortcut scrolls one line down, without moving the cursor. It would be acceptable also to run a command from the minibuffer and then ... i guess that there is some shortcut to repeat the last command even though i can't find it at the moment. I tried commands `scroll-down` and `scroll-down-line` from the minibuffer but it looks like they did nothing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but would this do the job:

```
(defun move-and-recenter ()
  (interactive)
  (next-line)
  (recenter-top-bottom 0)
  )


(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") 'move-and-recenter)
```